# Laravel Scout - searchableAs index

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Thread that I am indexing to Algolia and i want to be able to only allow user to search by the title and body of the thread.

So in my thread model:

```
  /**
     * Get the index name for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'title';
    }

     /**
     * Get the indexable data array for the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $array = $this->toArray();

        // Customize array...
        unset($array['created_at'],$array['updated_at']);

        return $array;
    }
```

So the first method is to index a specific column of the thread table and the second method is to choose which columns to place it in algolia.

I guess my question is what is searchableAs() for as I am confused with the explanation by the doc?